# Android aar file required dependencies are not loading

Tags: android, dependencies, aar

I have a issue in loading the dependencies from maven centeral repository
I have a library project and my different client uses my library. My library has dependency on GoolgePlayService as well as appcompat-v7. 
Recently I start using Gradle instead of ant. So I used andoird-library plugin and I pushed my library.aar file into my local depenency. 
Now in my TestApp I loaded aar file from local maven, but it is not loading the depenecy file from maven central repository.

The below is my build.gradle file

apply plugin: 'android-library'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'

version = "1.0.0_Build-1"
group = "com.sflibrary"

 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

dependencies {
     compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
     }
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
     compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
     compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}


android {
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']

            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']

            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']

            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

        }


        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

}

uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repository(url: "file://${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository/")
    }
  }
}
```

When I run "gradle uploadArchives" it is able to upload into my local mavel repository and its pom file looks as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <groupId>com.sflibrary</groupId>  
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0.0_Build-1</version>  
  <packaging>aar</packaging>  
  <dependencies>  
        <dependency>  
           <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>  
           <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>  
           <version>4.0.30</version>  
      <scope>compile</scope>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>  
      <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>  
      <version>+</version>  
      <scope>compile</scope>  
    </dependency>  
  </dependencies>  
</project>
```

The below is my TestApp build.gradle file 

   `apply plugin: 'android'
   apply plugin: 'maven'`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {

    compile('com.snapfish:library:1.0.0_Build-1@aar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.1.jar')
}


android {
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']

            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']

            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']

            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

        }
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

}
```

I am getting below error

```
   Error Code:
        1
      Output:
        /opt/usr/dev/gradel/AndroidSDK/TestApp/build/res/all/debug/values/values.xml:1549: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.  
        /opt/usr/dev/gradel/AndroidSDK/TestApp/build/res/all/debug/values/values.xml:1552: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'background'.  
        /opt/usr/dev/gradel/AndroidSDK/TestApp/build/res/all/debug/values/values.xml:1556: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'subtitleTextStyle'.
```

However it is working fine if I again speciy my library dependencies in my TestApp build.gradle file dependencies section. This mean its loading my library.aar file from local maven repository but not loading appcompat-v7 from maven central repository.

I don't know what the mistake I did here.

Thanks in advance
Samba Damerla

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was able to get it to work by:

- uploading the aar files into our my Nexus
- add my Nexus to allprojects:repositories:maven:url
- specify transitive=true on the dependency, like:

  ```
  compile('com.snapfish:library:1.0.0_Build-1@aar'){
      transitive=true
  }
  ```
- If I am pulling in SNAPSHOT Maven builds, I also have to set this:

  ```
  configurations.all {
      // check for updates every build (If a version number ends in -SNAPSHOT it is implicitly changing when looking for it in a maven repository)
      resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, gradle does not handle transitive dependencies

See this answer for more detail:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20530181/115145

"Only the repository declarations for the project whose configuration is
currently resolved are taken into account, even when transitive
dependencies are involved."